# Byte alignment used in implementing Threaded Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, algorithm

The struct used to compose the leaf of the tree:

```
typedef struct bstree_node bstree_node_t;
struct bstree_node {

    uintptr_t left, right;

} __attribute__((aligned(2)));
```

Just embed the struct into the user struct to use it:

```
struct leaf {

    int key;

    bstree_node_t node;

};
```

To access pointer to leaf or thread:

```
static inline void _bstree_set_thread(bstree_node_t *t, uintptr_t *p)

{

    *p = (uintptr_t) t | 1;

}

static inline bstree_node_t *_bstree_get_thread(uintptr_t u)

{

    return (bstree_node_t *) ((u & -(int) (u & 1)) & ~1UL);

}

static inline void _bstree_set_link(bstree_node_t *n, uintptr_t *p)

{

    *p = (uintptr_t) n;

}

static inline bstree_node_t *_bstree_get_link(uintptr_t u)

{

    return (bstree_node_t *) (u & ((int) (u & 1) - 1));

}
```

I suppose it is assocaited with `__attribute__((aligned(2)));`.
How to understand the code?

Comment: The code is using the lower bit of the pointer to store 1 bit of information. This is a technique used in trees (e.g. AVL trees) to store the balance information. So `(aligned(2))` intends that the that the LSB of a node pointer is always 0, and therefore available for use as hidden storage.

Comment: why "(aligned(2)) intends that the LSB of a node pointer is always 0"? :(

Comment: Because if the structure's address is a multiple of 2, then the LSB of the address is 0.